# How would you estimate the time complexity for this algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

Let N=number of vertices
    M=number of edges
of a directed graph G.We are storing the edges in the form of an adjacency list.
For clarity, let's assume, that Oi is the outdegree of vertex i, and Ii is the in-degree of vertex i.

The algorithm is as follows:

```
for each vertex i
  for each vertex j in i's adj.list
    //do some work
    for each vertex k in j's adj.list
      //do some work
```

The "do some work" is essentially done in constant time (O(1)).I couldn't derive a general expression of running time in N,M.Can someone explain how to do this?

As an aside:
Just to prevent the "I will not do your homework" comments, I'm practicing in-text questions(this one's 22.1-5) from CLRS.I am doing this to learn how to estimate time complexity for graph algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm supposing that each adjacency list mentioned in the algorithm is an outgoing edges list.  If instead both incoming and outgoing edges are referred to, the total work would multiply by a constant factor of 4, not affecting the O() level.

Referring to the `for` statements as F1, F2, F3, we have F1 looping N times.  F2 loops a total of `O1+O2+... = M` times, where `Oi` are the outgoing-edge degrees mentioned in the question.  F3 loops at most N times per F2 pass, and the worst case does not have a smaller lower bound than that.  This leads to O(M·N) time for the algorithm (that is, O(M) from F1 and F2, O(N) per F3).